# Can a service account access all APIs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iam

For an api-key, one can define which APIs can be accessed with that api-key, but for service accounts, you seemingly can't. I thought maybe I could create a new role that only allows access to the vision API, but there is no permission for that.

How do you decide which APIs (e.g. vision API) a service account can call?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AutoML roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#automl-roles) that grant a service account access to AI & Machine Learning Products only. In the meantime, I have submitted a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155913349) to implement fine-grained roles to access Vision only.